# Why fread doesn't work right?

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread, fseek

this program should take in input a number `n` and so create n triangles. After, I want to write this triangles in a file and to print this file on standard output. I don't understand why if I input `n` = `2` the program prints only one triangle's coordinates. Moreover if I input coordinates: `1.0,1.1-1.5,1.6-2.4,2.5` for the triangle's vertices, output is `2.4,2.5-0.0,0.0-0.0,0.0`. Can someome help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct{

    float x;
    float y;

} Punto;

typedef struct{

    Punto p1;
    Punto p2;
    Punto p3;

} Triangolo;

Punto creaPunto();
void creaTriangolo(Triangolo *);
void stampaPunto(Punto);
void stampaTriangolo(Triangolo);
void creaFileTriangoli(char[], int);
void stampaFileTriangolo(char[]);

Punto creaPunto(){

    Punto p;

    printf("Inserire la coordinata x: ");
    scanf("%f", &p.x);
    printf("Inserire la coordinata y: ");
    scanf("%f", &p.y);

    return p;
}
void creaTriangolo(Triangolo *t){

    printf("Triangolo.\n");

    printf("Vertice p1:\n");
    t->p1 = creaPunto();
    printf("Vertice p2:\n");
    t->p2 = creaPunto();
    printf("Vertice p3:\n");
    t->p3 = creaPunto();
}


void stampaPunto(Punto v){

    printf("Coordinata x: %f\n", v.x);
    printf("Coordinata y: %f\n", v.y);
}

void stampaTriangolo(Triangolo t){

    printf("Triangolo\n");
    printf("Vertice p1:\n");
    stampaPunto(t.p1);
    printf("Vertice p2:\n");
    stampaPunto(t.p2);
    printf("Vertice p3:\n");
    stampaPunto(t.p3);
}

void creaFileTriangoli(char f[], int n){

    FILE *ptr;
    Triangolo t;
    int i;

    ptr = fopen(f, "wb");

    if(ptr == NULL){

        printf("File inesistente.\n");
    }
    else{

        for(i=0; i<n; i++){

            creaTriangolo(&t);
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(Triangolo), 1, ptr);
        }
    }
}


void stampaFileTriangolo(char f[]){

    FILE *ptr;
    Triangolo t;

    ptr = fopen(f, "rb");

    if(ptr == NULL){

        printf("File inesistente.\n");
    }
    else{

        fseek(ptr, sizeof(Triangolo), SEEK_SET);

        while(!feof(ptr)){


            fread(&t, sizeof(Triangolo), 1, ptr);
            stampaTriangolo(t);

        }

        fclose(ptr);

    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *ptr;
    char f[300] = "C:\\sole.dat";
    Triangolo t;
    int n;
    float perimetro;

    printf("Inserire il numero di triangoli da analizzare: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    creaFileTriangoli(f,n);
    stampaFileTriangolo(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create an _[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_

Comment: I think is MCVE yet

Comment: See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).  You also fail to check any return values from `fwrite()` or `fread()` - and you also need to check the return value from `fclose()`.  How do you know the `fwrite()` calls succeeded?

Comment: What is the purpose of `fseek(ptr, sizeof(Triangolo), SEEK_SET);`? This line causes you to skip the first triangle.

Comment: @s7amuser i thought that I could read the file from the start with that `fseek` . I try to delete it,but output is the same.

Comment: write `fclose` at `creaFileTriangoli`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I do it, bur output is the same

Comment: It seems to work correctly if you've already fixed the place pointed out. Try the folder is not a root folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in `stampaFileTriangolo`, the first is that you skip the first record by using `fseek`. Note that when a file is opened, the file pointer is at the start of the file, and after you use `fread`, the file pointer is advanced automatically. So you don't need to call `fseek` to read a file sequentially.

The second is the abuse of `feof`, which does not do what many people think. It tells you *after* you have read beyond the file, not when there is no more data. I suggest using the return value from `fread` to control the loop, like this

```
void stampaFileTriangolo(char f[]){
    FILE *ptr;
    Triangolo t;
    ptr = fopen(f, "rb");
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        printf("File inesistente.\n");
    }
    else {
        while (fread(&t, sizeof(Triangolo), 1, ptr) == 1) {
            stampaTriangolo(t);
        }
        fclose(ptr);
    }
}
```

There is an error also in `creaFileTriangoli` - you have not closed the file. This may have caused you to think you needed an `fseek` here.